# how to handle multi-tab sharing same session in primefaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

We have list of employes and on clicking the employee name, we are displaying the details of that employee. Now if we Open new tab and clicking the first employee name in first tab. We are doing same for second employee name in second tab. We have our bean in session scope and We clicked last as second employee, if we refresh first tab, We will see data of second employee

In our Application we are using
1. Spring 3.1
2. JSF 2.0 (javax.faces-2.1.13.jar)
3. Primefaces 3.4.2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add some code to your question, then you may have a chance of getting help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR MyFaces Orchestra, which is a add-on lib based on JSF and Spring, provides a multi window handling but i'm not fimiliar with it.

I suggest to use CDI and DeltaSpike.
DeltaSpike provides a good window handling and provides a WindowScoped, which is like a sesion per browser tab.
ViewAccessScoped and GroupedConversationScoped are build on top of this scope.